# How do I get the row number of the last cell in a column,which is greater than zero?

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried with

```
=INDEX($K$2:K15,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($K$2:K15>0,0),))
```

but this gives me the value of last cell in K row which is greater than zero.
How do I get the number of the row where last non-zero value lives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Drag down

`=INDEX(FILTER(ROW(K2:K15),K2:K15>0),1)`

`FILTER(ROW(K2:K15),K2:K15>0)` is to get all rows where column values > 0. The index is to get the first one.

To get the last row number:

`=INDEX(FILTER(ROW(K2:K15),K2:K15>0),COUNTIF(K2:K15,">0"))`

This formula for row2: `=INDEX(FILTER(ROW($K$2:K2),$K$2:K2>0),COUNTIF($K$2:K2,">0"))`. Drag down and see if it works. Gives #N/A if no rows were found

---

## Single formula solution

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(K2:K16), QUERY(QUERY( { row(K2:K16) , IF(K2:K16>0,ROW(K2:K16),0) } , "select Col2, min(Col1) group by Col2"),"select Col2, Col1"), 2))`

Paste in a cell from row2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but something doesn't seem right. I have two nonzero values in colon K - first in K6 and the second in K15. Your formula is calculated for each cell in colon K. The value returned is always 6 although it should be 15 for cells from K15 on.
I have changed the formula to this =INDEX(FILTER(ROW($K$2:K16),$K$2:K16>0),1) for K16 field and so on.

Comment: Hm, still not ok. Check this sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEU7bqXFZpPopy2eKVksCwos3bowCutTuAjPOODQpls/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hm, sorry. Doesn't work. You can edit spreadsheet and try yourself.